# Authenticate device using an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

What if the business requirement is to make sure that the iOS device using your application should be an authorized device, how should the authentication be done?

Let's say the business have 1000 users and they are afraid that a user will download the app on another device other than on the one assigned to them.

I asked this because device id cannot be obtained anymore in iOS and no answers from the existing posts tackle this issue.

Has there been any new approach to this issue? Thanks

EDIT: app does not and will not support ads

Comment: Is this an Enterprise deployment or from the app store?

Comment: deployment on appstore, business does not want to spend on apple's b2b solution if that's what you will suggest :(

Comment: By "spend on apple's b2b solution" you mean they do not want to pay the additional $200/year? That they distribute the app through the app store?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: not sure what you are pointing but i guess any transactions from the old device will be invalid. i think they would want to save the valid serial numbers (device id's) in a database and each time the app will transact, the device's serial number will be validated against their database.

Comment: Better check that not allowing all devices associated with an App Store Apple ID is not a violation of the App Store requirements.

Comment: Normally that would be done by providing your customer with some kind of login information which they use to login to your app on the designated devices. To ensure that no unregistered devices are allowed to proceed you may want to lock the access until the login data has been verified.